# HTTPS POST Security level

Tags: ios, security, post, https

I've searched for this a bit on Stack, but I cannot find a definitive answer for https, only for solutions that somehow include http or unencrypted parameters which are not present in my situation.

I have developed an iOS application that communicates with MySQL via Apache HTTPS POSTS and php.

Now, the server runs with a valid certificate, is only open for traffic on port 443 and all posts are done to https://thedomain.net/obscurefolder/obscurefile.php

If someone knew the correct parameters to post, anyone from anywhere in the world could mess up the database completely, so the question is: Is this method secure? Let it be known nobody has access to the source code and none of the iPads that run this software are jailbreaked or otherwise compromised.

Edit in response to answers:
There are several php files which alone only support one specific operation and depend on very strict input formatting and correct license key (retreived by SQL on every query). They do not respond to input at all unless it's 100% correct and has a proper license (e.g. password) included. There is no actual website, only php files that respond to POSTs, given the correct input, as mentioned above. The webserver has been scanned by a third party security company and contains no known vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encryption is necessary but not sufficient for security. There are many other considerations beyond encrypting the connection. With server-side certificates, you can confirm the identity of the server, but you can't (as you are discovering) confirm the identity of the clients (at least not without client-side certficates which are very difficult to protect by virtue of them being on the client).

It sounds like you need to take additional measures to prevent abuse such as:

- Only supporting a sane, limited, well-defined set of operations on the database (not passing arbitrary SQL input to your database but instead having a clear, small list of URL handlers that perform specific, reasonable operations on the database).
- Validating that the inputs to your handler are reasonable and within allowable parameters.
- Authenticating client applications to the best you are able (e.g. with client IDs or other tokens) to restrict the capabilities on a per-client basis and detect anomalous usage patterns for a given client.
- Authenticating users to ensure that only authorized users can make the appropriate modifications.

You should also probably get a security expert to review your code and/or hire someone to perform penetration testing on your website to see what vulnerabilities they can uncover.

Comment: Thanks for your input.
As for point 1 and 2:
There are several php files which alone only support one specific operation and depend on very strict input formatting and correct license key (retreived by SQL on every query). They do not respond to input at all unless it's 100% correct and has a proper license (e.g. password) included.

Point 3 and 4 is not implemented.

There is no website. Only php files that respond to POSTs, given the correct input, as mentioned above. The webserver has been scanned by a third party security company and contains no known vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

**Sending POST requests is not a secure way of communicating with a server.** Inspite of no access to code or valid devices, it still leaves an open way to easily access database and manipulating with it once the link is discovered.

I would not suggest using POST. You can try / use other communication ways if you want to send / fetch data from the server. Encrypting the parameters can also be helpful here though it would increase the code a bit due to encryption-decryption logic.

Its good that your app goes through HTTPS. Make sure the app checks for the certificates during its communication phase.

You can also make use of tokens(Not device tokens) during transactions. This might be a bit complex, but offers more safety.

The solutions and ways here for this are broad. Every possible solution cannot be covered. You might want to try out a few yourself to get an idea. Though I Suggest going for some encryption-decryption on a basic level.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `I would not suggest using POST` - POST is no less secure than other means. POST with no other security is bad, however it is not intrinsically insecure so I would not advice against using POST at all.

Comment: @SilverlightFox This makes sense. I don't see a problem with using encrypted posts either - the issue is if someone was to decrypt a post and abuse the exposed parameters.

Comment: @nickdnk yes it's a tricky one. At the end of the day you cannot trust the client side end of the API access if the app is also maintaining it's own state because any of this data can be spoofed. As Michael Aaron Safyan mentioned - authentication for your users is the best you can do and your API access would use server side controls for their actions much like a web application.

Comment: @SilverLightFox This is where I'd claim that accessing the data on the client is damn near impossible in iOS terms as, as we all know, that's a very, very closed source-system. This is not national security level, and anyone who has access to the client hardware (the iPads) could mess up the database either way without ever having to know anything about computers anyway.
This app is not available on AppStore.

Comment: @nickdnk By spoofed, I mean data sent by things other than your app. You can trust your app to send the right data, but if it can be spoofed then your whole security model is gone. Client side in this case is _everything_ outside of your API.

Comment: I realize that - but how would any client ever gain access to the right parameters when these can only be found within a closed source system?